# Laravel Policies Best Practices

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new at Laravel, I'm making a mini-blog with Users and Post, everyone can see the posts and everyuser can delete and update their own post, so I'm using policies for authorization.

While creating my policies, I realized the code for both (delete/update), is the same

```php
public function update(User $user, Post $post)
{
    return $user->id === $post->user_id;
}

public function delete(User $user, Post $post)
{
    return $user->id === $post->user_id;
}
```

Should I keep it this way or should I make only one method because is redundant?
I mean if I only use one method I can aply it from the constructor of my PostController in one line to all Controller methods I want

```php
$this->middleware('can:policyMethodName, post')->except('show', 'index', 'create');
```

Which is the best practice to aply policies in Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a general question for programming and not a specific question to Laravel.

From a functionality standpoint, you will have to ask yourself what makes more sense. If you anticipate that this blog will *always* allow a user to update/delete their own post, then it might make sense to have a single method `canEditOrDelete`. However, in the future, if you think there's a chance you will want to restrict users from editing posts for *n* minutes, for example, then you need to re-program your logic. Hopefully, this doesn't matter *too* much because you're limiting the number of times you refer to this method.

If you want to get *really* fancy, you can use [bit-based permissions](https://www.sitepoint.com/bitwise-operators-still-relevant-modern-php/). It takes a bit of getting used to if you haven't used bit operations before, but it's a relative cakewalk and gives you a lot more flexibility.

```php
class Permissions {
    const CAN_EDIT = 1;
    const CAN_DELETE = 2;
    const CAN_EDIT_OR_DELETE = CAN_EDIT | CAN_DELETE; // in base-10, this is "3"
}

permissions($user, $post) & Permissions.CAN_EDIT_OR_DELETE; // returns true if user can edit or delete post.
```